# Структура данных меток вызывает недоумение

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Вот, как показано на снимке, сейчас для одной тематики по структурам данных используется аж четыре метки. Предлагаю сделать одну основную метку, а остальные сделать как синонимы. Впрочем лишние можно и удалить.

- [структура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)
- [структуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b)
- [структура-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)
- [структуры-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Not ehough pun!

Answer (score 5):

- [структура-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)
- [структуры-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Эти две точно синонимы. Синонимизировал и объединил.

По поводу просто структуры есть некоторые сомнения. Не во всех вопросах имеется в виду структура данных, например это может быть структура *базы* данных:

- [Структура базы данных для тестирования знаний](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494622/181472)
- [Правильная структура БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519756/181472)

А ещё бывает тип данных `struct` и прочее разное.

Предлагаю следующее:

1. Определить значение метки, сформировав хотя бы краткое описание.
2. Перебрать вручную вопросы с метками [структура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0), [структуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b) и произвести замену:

   - Речь о структурах данных → [структуры-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)
   - Речь о базах данных → [базы-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)
   - Что-то ещё? → найти нужную метку, если таковой нет, то вынести вопрос на обсуждение (комментарием к этому ответу).